# Is it possible to test Meteor application on multiple mobile phones?

Tags: meteor

I am developing audio calling application in Meteor and I would like to test if I can call other logged in users, it doesn't matter if it is IOS or Android.

Is it feasible to do so? If not, are there any way I can go about to test the calling functionality?

Comment: Does it need to be on a mobile? Can't you just use browser tests to do it?

Comment: Mikkel is right. Testing against the platform's browser engine will basically do it, since the cordova build will anyway wrap your app so that it uses a browser engine.

Comment: The audio functionality works between browsers but when I try to make a call (from android) to another user (web user) the call doesn't go through

Answer (score 0):

I’d build production apps and distribute to friends with something like Testfairy. I could be one of your testers if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly using webrtc technology so are your stun/turn servers configured correctly? I've read somewhere that a production build was required to access the device camera via the cordova plugin. That could very well be your problem.